# How can I fix the issue to reshape process in image derived from x_train in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, reshape, kaggle

I found a dataset from Kaggle Here is the link : https://www.kaggle.com/quangqiyana/human-gender-identity

I want to implement CNN algorithm into dataset.

I wrote some codes to get X_train and Y_train

```
train = pd.read_csv("files/gender.csv")
train.shape -> (230, 67502)
train.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1, inplace=True)
Y_train = train["Label"]
X_train = train.drop(labels = ["Label"],axis = 1)
```

Then I want to show some images by iloc process

```
img = X_train.iloc[0].to_numpy()
img = np.pad(img, (0, (67600-img.shape[0])), 'constant').reshape((260, 260))
plt.imshow(img)
plt.title(train.iloc[0,0])
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Because any number is not a square of `67502` , I can use `pad`. But the image couldn't show with resolution.

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

How can I fix the reshape issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dataset is likely not intended to be used with CNN, because the data encoded into the columns has no spatial relation to each other, like in images. Considering that this dataset was downloaded 1 (one) time, probably by you, and nobody has created any notebooks or deemed it worth a discussion, I'd recommend to move to another dataset, which has other people working on it, so you can ask questions there (on Kaggle) and get help.

Comment: There is a problem in reshape. I can also use `img = img.reshape((250,270))`. But I couldn't get image

Comment: @TonyBrand the data in .csv file is **not** an image. you may treat it as an image, but it won't get you any good.